# Array, pointer and Sizeof relation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have learned that we can use the address of elements of an array at index i as `&A[i]` or simply as `A+i`
and to get the value
`A[i]` or `*(A+i)`
where `A` is an array and `i` denotes the Index.
Let's say `int A[]={1,2,3};`

When I use `sizeof(*A)` I get value `4`, now when I use `sizeof(A)` I must get the size of `address value` of the first element why I get the size of the whole array as `12`.
I am a beginner and confused, please guide.

Comment: "when I use sizeof(A) I must get the size of address value" no, you should get the size of A. Since A is an array, you are getting the size of the array.

Comment: Since &A[i] is same as (A+i) , so if I do sizeof(A) , I must get the capacity of address pointing to array's first element , hope you understand

Comment: The rules of the language are such that if you say `sizeof(A)`, you get the size of `A`. Not the size of `(A+0)` and not the size of `&*A`. If you assume that A is always the same as A+0 etc. then you are mistaken.

Comment: `If you assume that A is always the same as A+0` no I assumed `A` as `&A[0]`

Comment: `&A[0]` *is* the same as `A+0` in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int A[]={1,2,3};
```

`A` is an `array` and `array is not a pointer`. when you are printing `sizeof(*A)` it prints `4` because `*A` means first element of array which size is `4`.

`sizeof(A)` will results not result in `4` because `A` is not a `pointer`. `A` is an `array` and `array` means collection of elements and each elements needs `4` bytes.

```
A[i] == *(A+i)
```

- `sizeof(A[i]) => 4` because `A[0]` is an integer
- `sizeof(*A)  => 4` because `*A` means value at starting address and that needs 4 bytes to store
- `sizeof(A) => 12 bytes`, not 4 because A is not a pointer.
- `sizeof(&A[0]) => 4 bytes` because `&A[0]` yields in address and size of any address will be `4` bytes.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `sizeof(A)` you get the size of the array as n.m said. But If you initialize your array as this:

```
    int *A = new int[3];
    A[0] = 1;
    A[1] = 2;
    A[2] = 3;
    cout << sizeof(A) << endl;
```

you will get 4.

Comment: Since `A` is equal to `&A[0]` for an array, so if I do `printf("%d",A)` I will get the address of first value in my case, so why does `sizeof(A)` don't function in same manner and tells me the sizeof address value pointing to first element of A.

Answer (score 0):

> When I use sizeof(*A) I get value 4

This is nothing but size of first element in the array ie `sizeof(*A)` is the same as `sizeof(*(&A[0]))`.

---

> now when I use sizeof(A) I must get the size of address value of the first element why I get the size of the whole array as 12

You have declared `A` as

```
int A[]={1,2,3};
```

Now, ask yourself a simple question - `What is A` ? Never settle with anything other than `Array` for an answer. In short you get the size of entire array in bytes. Here you have 3 elements which takes 4 bytes each.

**Added**

> I must get the size of address value

That should be `sizeof(&A)` -  which is the size of the address of A - which is usually 8 bytes in many systems.